# How to remove all digits in front only in a string using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to remove any digital character in front of alphabetical characters plus complex as the follow:

```
text = "12 132 2 5517 Publication Date: 12 June, 2012"
```

and after applying the regular expression it needs to look like ->

```
text = "Publication Date: 12 June, 2012"
```

I tried `/^\d+ /g` with no success, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex: `/^[\d ]+/gi`